# How to limit CPU and disk usage of rm to allow other programs to remain functional

Tags: linux, rm

When deleting a large file, `rm` seems to be hogging all the available CPU and disk resources so that other program are hanging.

Is there a way to limit a programs - specifically a CPU or disk intensive program - effect on the system? Is there a way to limit its effect when deleting a large file?

Answer (score 5):

`nice` (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29)) is the program to do that for you.  You can use `renice` for a running program.  Note that this only does CPU, there is a corresponding `ionice` (see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice))

Answer (score 0):

```
GETRLIMIT(2)

NAME
       getrlimit, setrlimit, prlimit - get/set resource limits

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/time.h>
       #include <sys/resource.h>

       int getrlimit(int resource, struct rlimit *rlim);
       int setrlimit(int resource, const struct rlimit *rlim);
       int prlimit(pid_t pid, int resource, const struct rlimit *new_limit,
               struct rlimit *old_limit);
```