# how much does "chown -R" affects disk IO performance? how can I test it?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, nas, io

I'm running a Cent OS server with a NAS storage.

I have heard "rm" command makes overall disk IO slow. So, I gave up doing `rm -R`. I will do `rm` one by one with a shell script. --EDIT--> `rm` and `sleep 0.1` one by one slowly.

Before I delete files, I want to change owner with "chown -R" command.

I have about 20,000,000 files to "chown". They are 2 TeraB in total in NAS storage.

I hope "chmod -R" won't affect too much on overall disk IO performance.

How about it? And, how can I measure the performance?

Comment: Where in the world did you hear that? And what makes you think that running multiple `rm` operations is better than running one big one?

Comment: I do rm and sleep 0.1 one by one with a script. Not for the better performance but for less burden in short time.

Comment: Just for the sake of discussion, how do you get the one filename you want to remove each time through the loop?

Comment: [for i in "$1"/*;do]
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154166/how-to-recursively-list-subdirectories-in-bash-without-using-find-or-ls-commands)

Comment: You may wish to refer [here](http://superuser.com/q/410986/117590) for the *correct* way to throttle `rm`'s disk usage. Also see [here](http://serverfault.com/a/336925/174582). Do note that those answers assume a local drive - and if you are running massive deletion operations, it would be better to run them directly on the NAS if possible.

Comment: `ionice` is really helpful! Thanks(+1). And, it seems [some](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-set-io-scheduling-class-priority.html) assume ionice will work for a network mounted NAS, too. I can't directly access NAS without network. But, I will have some benefits of `ionice`, right?

Comment: I found `ionice -c3` watches its(host's) own disk io (idle) status. `ionice -c3` idea was brilliant, but it does not work for my network mounted drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing `rm` one by one with a shell script will not be faster, it will do the exact same thing `rm -r` would do, just wasting more CPU time running in the shell rather than the fast C of `rm`. There is absolutely no sane reason to do a `chown -R` before you delete files, their owner won't matter after they are deleted. As for commands to measure how much I/O you are using, I would recommend `iotop`. It will show I/O usage broken down by process.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do `rm` and `sleep 0.1` one by one with a script. And, `chown -R` prevents my `rm` script from deleting other files.

Comment: CPU resource is enough. And, I'm worrying the disk IO performance for access of other files.

Comment: chown the files recursively to a new owner prevents the script from deleting other files, how? You changed ownership on everything to a new owner, you now delete everything. How will there be **other** files that this protects since they all now belong to the chown -R owner? There is a circular tail chasing logic to the description I'm not following.

Comment: Sorry for not enough information. I do `chown -R NewUser` immediately. And, I run the `rm` script as the NewUser a month later. I'm worrying  any bugs of my `rm` script. And, I have 1 month buffer to rollback any misses after I did `chown -R`. All of these will be done programmatically either by a batch or by an api. I omitted this explanation because this is not main topic of the question.

Answer (score 1):

`rm` does not affect disk I/O any more than any other command that needs to write to your disk. The only time I can think of when this will be a problem is if the disk in question is a network mounted drive. Large I/O operations can then indeed affect the entire network but it should make no difference whatsoever if the command you run is `rm` or `chmod` or `chown` or `mv` or whatever.

If you are experiencing latency problems when running multiple I/O operations, you will experience the same problems with `chown` and `rm`. If you have not noticed any problems when doing this, then just ignore it and run `rm -rf *` normally, you don't need to test it. The only test you need is to do it and find out if you can see problems. If you don't then forget about it.

Comment: "`rm -r` and `chown -r` has no big differences" is just what I wanted to know even though this was a bad news for me if it's true. Thanks(+1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any sort of disk monitors while "chown"ing your files, that's how you can measure your Disk I/O load.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to chown the files.

As for the I/O, you can use the iotop utility,

In case if you don't have it installed, you can install it first using the command:

yum install iotop # or att-get instal iotop